# ASP.NET Passing variable from .aspx page to UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that I want to pass a value to from my .aspx page.  I've setup a property in the usercontrol to set to the value I need from the page but the value is always null.

Here is my control code in the .aspx page,

```
<tcs:SubmitDataDiscrepancy runat="server" ID="SubmitDataDiscrepancy" EntityNameProp='<%# Bind("Association_Name") %>'/>
```

the .ascx code,

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
<asp:LinkButton ID="ReportLink" runat="server" Text="Report data discrepancy"></asp:LinkButton>
```

```
<asp:Panel ID="ReportPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="width:auto;">
<div id="PopHeader" style="background-color: black; color: white; height: auto;">
    Report discrepancy
        <div style="float: right;">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="AssociationCancelTextButton" CausesValidation="False" Font-Underline="false"
                CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-remove white" ToolTip="Close" />
        </div>
</div>
<div style="margin:10px;">
    <div>
        Submit change request for: <asp:Label ID="EntityName" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="reportTextArea" runat="server" class="form-control" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom:10px; width: 100%;"></textarea>
        <button id="reportSubmitButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the .ascx.cs page,

```
    public partial class SubmitDataDiscrepancy : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string EntityNameProp { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EntityName.Text = EntityNameProp;
    }
}
```

Why am I not getting the value I'm expecting from the .aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle, that's the stateless nature of HTTP. So you need a way to persist your property. You could for example  use `ViewState`, `Session` or a `HiddenField` ([Other ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)).

In this case it makes sense to simply use the `Label.Text`:

```
public partial class SubmitDataDiscrepancy : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string EntityNameProp { 
        get { return EntityName.Text; }
        set{ EntityName.Text = value; }
    }
}
```